Understanding Green's Function Derivation for Inhomogeneous Wave Equation
I am currently reading through Zangwill's Modern Electrodynamics. In Chapter 20, Zangwill derives the Green's function for the wave equation
$$[\nabla^2 - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}]\psi(\textbf{r},t)=-f(\textbf{r},t) \tag{20.26}$$
First, Zangwill states that the Green's function satisfies
$$[\nabla^2 - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}]G(\textbf{r},t | \textbf{r}',t')= - \delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}')\delta(t-t') \tag{20.27}$$
From there, quoting Zangwill,

We begin by multiplying (20.27) by $\psi(\textbf{r}', t')d^3 r' dt'$, replacing the derivatives by their primed counterparts, and integrating the result over a volume V and from an initial time $t_1$ to a final time $t_2$. This gives

$$\psi(\textbf{r},t) = \frac{1}{c^2}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt'd^3 r' \psi(\textbf{r}', t')\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t'^2}G(\textbf{r}, t | \textbf{r}', t) - \int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt'\int_{V}d^3 r' \psi(\vec{r}', t') \nabla'^2 G(\textbf{r}, t | \textbf{r'}, t) \tag{20.28}$$
The part I am having trouble understanding is "replacing the derivatives by their primed counterparts". In a footnote, Zangwill mentions

The correctness of this step follows directly from (20.26)

I'm having difficulty seeing how this can be justified from (20.26). Is there some kind of symmetry between the primed and unprimed components that can be derived from (20.26)? Or is a different argument being used here?

+1 I completely agree with you that this is a successful attempt to find the most confusing way explaining a simple derivation. It might be helpful to consult also other text-books on this subject. Concerning your question about the symmetry: The d'Alembert operator is invariant under space-time translations, as a consequence $G$ depends in fact only on the arguments $t-t^\prime$ and $\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^\prime$.
